# Is this a valid way to have C# classes share objects?

Tags: c#, sharing

I have a set of classes that are going to be serialized to xml files.   The classes share some data.  I have been looking at some similar questions but none of the ones seem to do it the way I would like to. Basically the approach that seems the best to me would be to create a base class that contains a object witch holds the data.  Then I can pass the data encapsulated in a object to derived classes through this object.  This way I do not have to have define fields in the classes to share a reference to this shared object.  I have written a simplified example of this approach and it seems to work the way I expected.

My question is this the best way to achieve this?  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
    public class SharedProperties
    {
        public int x = 0;
    }

    public class BaseA
    {
        private SharedProperties s;

        protected BaseA(SharedProperties sparm)
        {
            s = sparm;
        }

        public int spx { get => s.x ; set => s.x = value; }
    }

    public class Derived1 : BaseA
    {
        public Derived1() : base(null) { }

        public Derived1(SharedProperties x) : base(x) { }

    }

    public class Derived2 : BaseA
    {
        public Derived2() : base(null) { }

        public Derived2(SharedProperties x) : base(x) { }

    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SharedProperties sp = new SharedProperties();

            Derived1 d1 = new Derived1(sp);

            Derived2 d2 = new Derived2(sp);

            d1.spx = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("d2.spx = {0}", d2.spx);

            d2.spx = 2;

            Console.WriteLine("d1.spx = {0}", d1.spx);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Derived1().spx = 0;` boom, null pointer/reference exception ... guess which constructor would use XML deserializer ...

Comment: Typically if the base class needs to share variables with derived classes, it'll declare those variables as `protected`. Done. What are you doing that requires this different mechanism that you have come up with?

Comment: I can see that this might be useful, but your example in your question seems a little pointless. Can you explain how you are intending to actually use this?

Comment: What I am trying to do is:

Comment: I am writing a program that maps data to a XML layout to be written to a file.   Some of the data is stored multiple times in different nodes in the XML.  So I have the objects that can be serialized to the XML but  rather then save the data in each object I want to save the data once and use it in different objects from the same member.  The data only gets stored once but not all the objects may exist when I obtain the data.  In some cases there are arrays of objects/nodes that contain the same data.  I have no control over the XML schema

Answer (score 3):

Zen of Python says, that

> Explicit is better than implicit

Even if it's not a Python, this rule also works here. When you pass same `SharedProperties` parameter it's not obvious that changing `spx` in any of classes will affect other classes. It's debugging nightmare and very difficult to read and support. If you need shared properties, create separate class/service, inject it into your instances and modify parameters using it instead of modifying it implicitly using `spx` property.

Comment: +1 yours was faster and in short sentences excatly what I tried to answer with an example (but struggled a bit with .netfiddle to save the code snippets in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry changed your code a little bit to make it not that abstract.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;       

public class Program
{
    public class Color
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "blue";
    }

    public abstract class Cup
    {
        protected Color Color { get; private set; }
        protected Cup(Color color)
        {
            Color = color;
        }

        public string ColorName 
        { 
            get => Color.Name; 

            /// ATTENTION:
            /// Try to avoid setting properties of shared properties
            /// this will lead to errors and is very difficult to 
            /// find in debugging or searching for potential errors
            set => Color.Name = value; 
        }
    }

    public class TeaCup : Cup
    {
        public TeaCup() : base(null) { }
        public TeaCup(Color color) : base(color) { }
    }

    public class CoffeeCup : Cup
    {
        public CoffeeCup() : base(null) { }
        public CoffeeCup(Color color) : base(color) { }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var color = new Color();
        var cup1 = new TeaCup(color);
        var cup2 = new CoffeeCup(color);

        Console.WriteLine("color = {0}", color.Name);

        cup1.ColorName = "red";
        Console.WriteLine("cup1.ColorName = {0}", cup1.ColorName);
        Console.WriteLine("cup2.ColorName = {0}", cup2.ColorName);

        cup2.ColorName = "green";
        Console.WriteLine("cup1.ColorName = {0}", cup1.ColorName);
        Console.WriteLine("cup2.ColorName = {0}", cup2.ColorName);
    }
}
```

If you now change the `Color.Name` its is changed in every `Cup` implementation which was created with the same `color`. See the comment in the code.

I think it is better to explicitly set the `Color.Name` directly on the `Color` instance not forwared by another wrapping instance (`Cup`).

[First approch: .netfiddle link to try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Szfbgj)

So in my optinion a better approch is to inject something like a SharedProperties (`Color`) provider/service

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;       

public class Program
{
    public interface IColorProvider
    {
        string GetName();
    }

    public class ColorProvider : IColorProvider
    {
        private string _name = "blue";
        public void SetName(string name) { _name = name; }
        public string GetName() { return _name; }
    }

    public abstract class Cup
    {
        private readonly IColorProvider _colorProvider;
        protected Cup(IColorProvider colorProvider)
        {
            _colorProvider = colorProvider;
        }

        public string ColorName { 
            get => _colorProvider.GetName(); 
        }
    }

    public class TeaCup : Cup
    {
        public TeaCup() : base(null) { }
        public TeaCup(IColorProvider colorProvider) : base(colorProvider) { }
    }

    public class CoffeeCup : Cup
    {
        public CoffeeCup() : base(null) { }
        public CoffeeCup(IColorProvider colorProvider) : base(colorProvider) { }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var colorProvider = new ColorProvider();
        var cup1 = new TeaCup(colorProvider);
        var cup2 = new CoffeeCup(colorProvider);

        Console.WriteLine("color = {0}", colorProvider.GetName());

        colorProvider.SetName( "red");
        Console.WriteLine("cup1.ColorName = {0}", cup1.ColorName);
        Console.WriteLine("cup2.ColorName = {0}", cup2.ColorName);

        colorProvider.SetName( "green");
        Console.WriteLine("cup1.ColorName = {0}", cup1.ColorName);
        Console.WriteLine("cup2.ColorName = {0}", cup2.ColorName);
    }
}
```

[Second approch: .netfiddle link to try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A9HVWc)